# Difference between dispatch_get_main_queue and dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have just started working on iOS and have been going through Apple Reference material on GCD. `dispatch_get_global _queue` returns a concurrent queue to which one can submit a block to be executed.

However, we can achieve the same using `dispatch_get_main_queue` as well, right? Then, what exactly is the difference between `dispatch_get_global_queue` and `dispatch_get_main_queue`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The global queue is a background queue and executes its blocks on a non-main thread.  The main queue executes its blocks on the main thread.

You should put background work that does not involve changes to the user interface on the global queue, but use the main queue when the blocks make changes to the user interface.  A very common pattern, for example, is to execute a "work" block on the global queue, and to have the work block *itself* dispatch back to the main queue to update a progress indicator.

Comment: This is correct except that the global queues are not _guaranteed_ to be on other threads. Only the main queue is explicitly always on a particular thread. It's my understanding that GCD will use the main thread for a global queue if the workload allows it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: You seem to be right that the docs on `dispatch_get_global_queue` don't make any guarantees about which thread the global queue uses, but every bit of code I've ever seen that uses the global queue treats it as though it's a suitable place for work that should not occur on the main thread (because it might make the app unresponsive).  Do you think it's possible that the docs are just unclear, or have you actually seen global queue work occur on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Enqueuing a block synchronously to a background queue will reliably run the block on the original thread (and not just for the main thread): https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/5882484 From GCD's point of view, there's no reason to bother with switching threads since the original needs to wait anyways. For an asynchronously enqueued block, though, I am only guessing.

Answer (score 4):

`dispatch_get_main_queue` - should be used when you want to manipulate UI elements. 
(It gets a background queue that you can dispatch background tasks that are run asynchronously... it won't block your user interface)

`dispatch_get_global_queue` - Can be used for network calls/core data.